# onListItemClick() error: it must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-adapter

I am a beginner in both Android and Java. I searched for an answer to this error, but nothing in stackOverflow worked for my situation. I am following a book that says we need to use a onListItemClick() method that is from a class (CrimeListFragment) we created that extends ListFragment (using the method and the class are mandatory).

However, I keep getting the error with:

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView 1, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Crime c = (Crime)(getListAdapter()).getItemViewType(position);
        Log.d(TAG, c.getTitle() + " was clicked");
    }
```

The error says

> "The method on onListItemClick of type CrimeListFragment must override
>   or implement a supertype method."

It also has a problem with the List View 1 argument. That shows an error too.

This project is complicated with many classes, but here is the main code for this page:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static final String TAG = "CrimeListFragment";
    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;



    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView 1, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Crime c = (Crime)(getListAdapter()).getItemViewType(position);
        Log.d(TAG, c.getTitle() + " was clicked");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.crimes_title);
        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();

        ArrayAdapter<Crime> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Crime>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCrimes);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

HOW do I get rid of these 2 errors? Thank you.

Comment: the '1' is not a proper variable. you should use a1, for example

Comment: thanks Tal, but on the Android developer website, it seems to be okay to have a 1 there, I think (?): 

'onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)' 
This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: they use 'l' and not '1'

Comment: Is that the letter I (as in Iceland) or the lower case letter l (as in lamp)? I tried those both and I still get errors. I also tried | (pipe) and that doesn't work.

Comment: its l as in lamp. whats the error now?

Comment: Ah good! sort of... I changed it to l (lamp) and I tried again to update imports, and there was no Log import, so I did that and saved, and it got rid of the error on that line... but now i have a new error on the `Crime c` line: `@Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
 {
  Crime c = (Crime)(getListAdapter()).getItemViewType(position);
  Log.d(TAG, c.getTitle() + " was clicked");
 }`

The error says **cannot cast from int to Crime**.

Comment: try this: (crime) getListAdapter().getItemViewType(position);

Comment: nah, it is still the same error. also the (Crime) is a class, so must be capitalized.

Comment: but whats the error exactly?

Comment: It only says **cannot cast from int to Crime**.

Comment: getItemViewType(...) returns an int (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html). Why are you trying to cast it to Crime? It won't work.

Comment: OMG, i figured it out. I use auto-fill with the code, a lot, and I accidentally put in `.getItemViewType()` instead I should have put `.getItem()`. i must be getting tired :( i always double check my code before coming to stackOverflow. oh well, the error went away!!

Comment: thanks Jk1, that was the culprit!!

Comment: @Jk1, I'm curious though, how did you know that `getItemViewType()` was not going to work? It is because you saw I had an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. I was able to correct the error of changing the 1 (number) to an l (as in lamp) letter, and that got rid of one error. Then a new one came up, which said:

> Cannot cast from int to Crime

I couldn't figure it out. But then (after checking for the fourth time) I checked my code again for errors in transcription (from the book), and it turns out the auto-fill I choose by accident the `.getItemViewType()` when it should have been the `.getItem()` method. So now it more specific to accepting the `int position` since that parameter is for an array, which is what I am using it for in my code.

The `getItem()` comes from ArrayAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Whereas the `getItemViewType()` comes from Adapter, which is not what I want to use.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Thanks everyone for your help though! It definitely fixed one of the errors. It's always strange to me that an error pops up ONLY after your correct another one. But at least it works now!

Answer (score 1):

When giving names to variables or method parameters in Java one should follow  these rules:

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>   underscore character "*". **The convention, however, is to always begin
>   your variable names with a letter**, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the
>   dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
>   find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
>   dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
>   similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
>   technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this
>   practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.
>
> Subsequent characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or
>   underscore characters. Conventions (and common sense) apply to this
>   rule as well. When choosing a name for your variables, use full words
>   instead of cryptic abbreviations. Doing so will make your code easier
>   to read and understand. In many cases it will also make your code
>   self-documenting; fields named cadence, speed, and gear, for example,
>   are much more intuitive than abbreviated versions, such as s, c, and
>   g. Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or
>   reserved word.
>
> If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell that word in
>   all lowercase letters. If it consists of more than one word,
>   capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word. The names
>   gearRatio and currentGear are prime examples of this convention. If
>   your variable stores a constant value, such as static final int
>   NUM_GEARS = 6, the convention changes slightly, capitalizing every
>   letter and separating subsequent words with the underscore character.
>   By convention, the underscore character is never used elsewhere.

You're clearly violating them by using "1" as a parameter name. Rename it to conform the naming rules, it should solve both of the compilation problems.

For additional information please refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: thanks Jk1, it came from the book... i did not think it was a variable name, but rather the #1 item from the ListView (?) ... on the Android developer site, it seems to look like a #1 is there:

`onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`
This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html